# Ajax is not sending FormData

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, form-data

i have a form with enctype of `multipart/form-data` and i am sending file (image) with FormData and ajax but as i see it is not sending. here is code

```
 $(document).ready(()=>{
     $('#form').submit((e)=>{
         e.preventDefault();
         const formData = new FormData();
         const title = $('#title').val();
         const news = $('#news').val();
         formData.append('title', title);
         formData.append('news', news);
         formData.append('img', $('#form').find('input[type="file"] [name="thumbnail"]:first')[0].files[0]);
         $.ajax({
             url: '/admin-panel/add-news',
             method: 'POST',
             data: formData,
             processData: false,
             contentType: false,
             success: (r)=>{
                 $('#news-container').html(`<div class="news">${r.news}</div>`);
             },
             error: (xhr,textStatus,error)=>{
                 try{ 
                    const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    if(response.message){
                        $('#error').html(`<p class="err">${response.message}</p>`);
                    }
                 }catch(error){
                    $('#error').html(`<p class="err">${xhr.responseText}</p>`);
                 }
             }
         })
     })
 })
```

but it gives me error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files'

what is problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Get rid of the space in `[type="file"] [name="thumbnail"]`. The space makes it look for a child, not the same element with both attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Check your ajax property - contentType